# Data visualization / analytics / dashboard in ASP.NET (NOT Google analytics integration)

Tags: asp.net, database, graphics, visualization, analytics

I need to create an ASP.NET site which can display graphs, charts, statistics for a dashboard type application pulling data from a backend data source.

I am trying to locate either:

(a) open-source modules that I can use / build up on

(b) tutorials which teach the above

(c) existing modules (preferably low-cost) that work well.

I did the basic googling, but found only VERY expensive paid solutions (eg: http://www.dundas.com/ $700+, http://www.devexpress.com/ $300 * n).

Answer (score 3):

For simple visualizations, you should take a look at the EXTJS library. It's a free javascript framework. 
http://www.sencha.com/products/js/

There are several good examples of dynamic charts there and I've found the API is pretty easy to use.

A non-free library that you can always go to is Adobe's Flex platform. That will give you more of a sexy front end. A basic license for Flash Builder (which comes with the Flex library) is only $249, so that may be within your budget.

Comment: Hi Mad - that looks good too, but its just TOO expensive! I'm not sure about Flex because that would be an additional constraint on the enduser's system...

Comment: It's free unless you plan to create a proprietary product out of it. If that is the case, you can purchase a developer license, which should cover you, for around $219 (I would hope your profit would be larger than that!). Until you are ready to sell, you can develop under an open source license.

You probably looked at the page that bundles the license with support, which you don't need to buy unless you require vendor support.

Answer (score 2):

If you can publish your data as JSON objects and have the results displayed in a browser, Protovis is a free JS library that's pretty nice to work with:

https://mbostock.github.io/protovis/

Comment: Wow - this is very interesting... its not specific to ASP.NET, but nevertheless it looks visually stunning!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is shipped with everything you need to build the application without having to purchase additional components.

(a) there are plenty of open source projects around charting. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx

(b) there are plenty ASP.NET tutorials on the next including ones related to charting. Google is your friend here!

See point a (if I understand well what you are asking for).