# MVC Web App via TV Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, monitor

I was planning to create a MVC web app that displays graphs and charts that Is built from LIVE data. The app would display the charts in a carousel style. 4 pages total.

My question is:

1) Is there a framework or tool that does most of this for me? If so, I would just have to create the graphs and chart

2) What hardware/Software do I need to display this on a TV monitor that is remote? (i.e monitor on a shop flop of a production plant)

3) What are other options instead of a web app? (i.e create a console app that generates a .png and spit out to a file location on a shared drive. The TV would cycle through the images when pointed to the shared folder)

Something similar to this question

[Data visualization / analytics / dashboard in ASP.NET (NOT Google analytics integration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289970/data-visualization-analytics-dashboard-in-asp-net-not-google-analytics-inte)

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 of your question are off-topic (request for recommendation of off-site resource).

Comment: ...and part 3 is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar revolving dashboard setup that consist of the following: 
1. Standard TV 
2. Standard networked PC with monitor cable going to TV
3. PC configured not to go to sleep/display screen saver
4. Browser open and in full screen mode, navigated to my internal MVC website
5. MVC site using bootstrap template with NAV removed.
6. MVC site utilizes highcharts for ease of generating my dashboard components.
7. Main display page (Home controller Index view) includes js that fires off Ajax calls to controller to fetch data from my DB and responds with json to reload/refresh my highcharts displays on Ajax get response every 5 minutes on a counter.

Maybe this can point you in the right direction. When researching when I was going to do it I also considered a wpf application that functions similar to a screen saver to load dynamically created images. What won me over with my current setup was ease of use of highcharts. It's an insanely easy, free, and produces high quality graphics. That combined with twitter-bootstrap for auto screen sizing made the project a breeze. I'm sure if you can get ahold of a smart TV to negate the need for a connected PC then it may be even easier if a physical setup for you.